# CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed in unity

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, gradle, android-augmented-reality

When I'm going to build augmented reality based android application using unity game engine I'm getting the following error.

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.13f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.13f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleDebug"
```

I tried lots of solutions. But none of them are worked. Can someone help me to fix this error.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: so where is the error? there is no error in log you provided